# Haskell - reading from file, parse expressions, compute and return result

Tags: haskell

I'm quite new to Haskell and I want to work a bit with parsers. 
I'm trying to create a small program that will read an expression from a text.txt file and will return the result.

First of all I read the text and convert what I read to a string:

```
module Main where
import Data.Char

convert :: String -> String
convert = unlines . (map convertLine) . lines

convertLine :: String -> String
convertLine = unwords . (map convertWord) . words

convertWord :: String -> String
convertWord s = (toUpper (head s)):(tail s)

main = do
    name <- readFile "test.txt"
    putStr $ convert name
```

Now, I want to parse that string and I start with:

```
parse :: (Read a, Num a, Fractional a) => String -> [SyntacticalElement a]
parse "" = []
parse putStr = element : (parse rest)
                   where (element, rest) = next_elem putStr
```

Here I get the error: next_elem is not in scope
Any idea why?

Update:

```
module Main where
import Data.Char

convert :: String -> String
convert = unlines . (map convertLine) . lines

convertLine :: String -> String
convertLine = unwords . (map convertWord) . words

convertWord :: String -> String
convertWord s = (toUpper (head s)):(tail s)

main = do
    name <- readFile "test.txt"
    putStr $ convert name

number = ['0'..'9']  ++ ['.']
operator = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
open_brackets  = ['(', '[']
close_brackets = [')', ']']
brackets = open_brackets ++ close_brackets
allowed_chars = number ++ operator ++ brackets

parse :: (Read a, Num a, Fractional a) => String -> [SyntacticalElement a]
parse "" = []
parse putStr = element : (parse rest)
                   where (element, rest) = next_elem putStr
next_elem :: (Read a, Num a, Fractional a) => String -> (SyntacticalElement a, String)
next_elem s@(first:_)
| is_open_bracket first  = (to_sublist content, rest_b)
| is_operator first      = (to_operator operator, rest_o)
| is_number first        = (to_number number, rest_n)
| is_close_bracket first = error "Unexpected closing bracket!"
| otherwise              = error $ "Invalid Expression: \"" ++ s ++ "\""
where (number,   rest_n) = span is_number s
      (operator, rest_o) = span is_operator s
      (content,  rest_b) = parse_bracket s
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler doesn't know what `next_elem` means. Why would it? Where is it defined?

Btw for these situations it's often handy to use `interact` rather than bothering to read from a file.

Comment: Good observation. I just defined it (hope I did it right) with `next_elem :: (Read a, Num a, Fractional a) => String -> (SyntacticalElement a, String)` and now I get _parse error on input_ for next_elem

Comment: Maybe you could update the question with the full code? Also what you gave there is a type signature rather than a definition. Also a parse error usually indicates a typo.

Comment: I just updated it. I checked it a few times, Don't think that there is any typo.. (maybe just logic ones).

Comment: @user140102 It looks like you haven't included a definition for `next_elem`, just a type signature.  Is that correct?

Comment: @user140102 After your most recent edit, if what you have posted is the code you're working with then you need to indent your guards and the `where` clause.  I don't see any other syntax errors in your code for `next_elem`.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what do you want to say with _need to indent your guards and the where clause._

Comment: @user140102 The lines starting `|` and the line starting `where` need to be indented more than the `next_elem` line which they are continuing.